# Host for socket programming

Tags: c++, sockets, host

I am studying socket programming. So far, I was able to do it on local host. However, is there an online hosting with shell access, so I can put my practice into real environment?

I heard cloud service like http://www.heroku.com/ allow shell access, though I never try it before.

Comment: You computer uses the same TCP/IP that servers use. Provided that you're not using insane amounts of bandwidth, or being really latency dependent, it doesn't matter whether you're doing on local loopback (127.0.0.1) or across the public internet.

Comment: @Nick in fact is does matter. Sockets do behave differently in some cases when operating with localhost addresses. So it's a good idea to test with something other than localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to mess around a bit while you learn something, I would recommend Amazon AWS you can deploy a VM running any OS you want in a few minutes. It is also a great skill to put on a resume and its free if you don't use it much:

http://aws.amazon.com/free/

Answer (score 3):

Run another OS under virtual machine. This will give you complete control over that separate "host".